# Unable to create aggregate of worker values across Sector in PIG (ERROR 1066)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, data-science

Brand new to PIG and just trying to create an aggregate of industry sectors by city and by patrons and am struggling to do so.  I am receiving `ERROR 1066: Unable to open iterator for alias test`

My goal is to rank industry sectors by number of workers within each city.  Something to the effect of `New York City: Finance 20, Accounting 15, Shoemaking 30`, etc. What am I missing or doing wrong?

```
bus_data = LOAD 'sectorAnalysis.json' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') as (row: map[]);

bus_data_rows = FOREACH bus_data GENERATE (chararray) row# 'city' AS city, row# 'state' AS state, row# 'sectors' AS sectors, row# 'workers' AS workers;

flattened_bus = FOREACH bus_data_rows GENERATE city, state, FLATTEN(sectors) as sector, workers;

distinct_flat_bus = DISTINCT flattened_bus;

group_by_sec = GROUP distinct_flat_bus BY (city, sector);

sum_sec = FOREACH group_by_sec GENERATE flatten(group) AS (city, sector), SUM(workers) AS worker_T;

DUMP sum_sec;
```

**data format:**

```
(Brookville, NY, (product 1), 12)
(Tempe, AZ, (product 3), 13)
(Brookville, NY, (product 1), 9)
(Miami, FL, (Product 2), 10)
(Brookvile, NY, (product 2), 15)
```

**The desired end result would look something the following:**

```
(Brookville, NY, (product 1), 21)
(Brookville, NY, (product 2), 15)
(Tempe, AZ, (product 3), 13)
(Miami, FL, (Product 2), 10)
```

Comment: Please show your JSON data

Comment: are you sure about the error as you don't have alias `test` in your script at all?

Comment: @Alexey That's definitely the exception that is thrown.  Whether that's the actual error or not I guess is another story.

Comment: @cricket_007 sure

Comment: I'm still not seeing json in the question

Comment: @cricket_007 I can't post the JSON as the information is confidential

Comment: Then remove the confidential piece or make up fake data... It's hard to help you parse something we can't see